# html tags in notepad++

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I am looking for plugin to notepad++, which can add html tags at the begining of the selected text and at the end f.e.:

I have:

```
good day
```

after I select `good day` and click plugin it will add `<b>good day</b>`

Where can I find it??

Comment: Good question, thumb up. I'm looking for the same plugin for NP++. For now I use Adobes Dreamweaver and the shortcut for `<b>` tag there is `Ctrl + b`. It puts `<strong>...</strong>` around the selected segment.

Answer (score 0):

The [zen coding plugin](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) has a "wrap with abbreviation" feature that will wrap highlighted text with any tag. It is not as quick as `Ctrl + b` but it does provide some other great features.